# ¿Cómo comparar dos tablas y omitir las coincidencias?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo la tabla llamada **usuarios**.

En dicha tabla se almacena el número interno que tiene cada empleado, su nombre y su hora de salida:

| no_empleado | nombre | salida |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Juan | 13:00 |
| 1002 | Lucía | 14:00 |

Tengo la tabla llamada **registros**.

En dicha tabla se guardan los registros de la fecha y hora en la que se retiró cada empleado de su lugar de trabajo:

| no_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-02-01 13:01:00 |
| 1002 | 2022-02-01 14:01:00 |
| 1001 | 2022-02-02 12:30:00 |
| 1002 | 2022-02-02 13:56:00 |

Tengo la tabla llamada **pases**.

En dicha tabla se lleva registro de los pases que se otorgaron a los empleados para que pudieran retirarse de su lugar de trabajo antes de su hora oficial de salida:

| no_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-02-02 |

Trabajé en la siguiente consulta para desplegar todas las ocasiones en las que un empleado dejó su lugar de trabajo antes de su hora de salida en un mes específico:

```
SELECT r.no_empleado, 
       u.nombre, 
       DAY(r.fecha) AS dia 
FROM usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN(SELECT no_empleado, fecha FROM registros) r ON r.no_empleado = u.no_empleado 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28' 
GROUP BY no_empleado, DATE(fecha)
```

Dicha consulta me despliega el número de empleado, su nombre y el día de febrero en el que algún empleado se retiró antes de tiempo. El resultado que se obtiene es el siguiente:

| no_empleado | nombre | dia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Juan | 2 |
| 1002 | Lucía | 2 |

También tengo la siguiente consulta para desplegar los pases que se otorgaron en el mes de febrero:

```
SELECT p.no_empleado, 
       u.nombre, 
       DAY(p.fecha) AS dia
FROM usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN(SELECT no_empleado, fecha FROM pases) p ON p.no_empleado = u.no_empleado 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28' 
GROUP BY no_empleado, DATE(fecha)
```

La consulta anterior despliega el siguiente resultado:

| no_empleado | nombre | dia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Juan | 2 |

Lo que busco es obtener a los empleados que salieron antes de su hora de salida y no cuentan con un pase. Con base al ejemplo que he expuesto anteriormente, Juan es el único que tiene un pase, por lo que Lucía es quien debería aparecer como resultado de quienes salieron antes de tiempo sin contar con un pase. El resultado deseado debería desplegarse de la siguiente manera:

| no_empleado | nombre | dia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | Lucía | 2 |

¿Cómo podría obtener dicho resultado? Estoy trabajando con MariaDB en phpMyAdmin con una versión que no soporta CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.no_empleado, u.nombre,DAY(r.fecha) AS dia  from usuarios u
LEFT join registros r ON r.no_empleado = u.no_empleado 
LEFT JOIN pases p ON p.no_empleado = u.no_empleado where p.no_empleado IS NULL
AND (r.fecha BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28')
```

Restaría agregar la condición de "dejó su lugar de trabajo antes de su hora de salida", la cual no me quedó claro en la pregunta o no la veo en la consulta de la pregunta pero entiendo que debería ser algo así como

```
AND r.fecha < u.salida
```